# sequelize making foreign keys composite and unique index.

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Here is my model ,

```
 var traders = sequelize.define('traders', {
   .....
  }, {});
```

it has many to many self association

```
 traders.belongsToMany(models.traders,{
    as:'feedbackClient',
    through:'feedback'
  });
```

idea is one trader can give feedback to other trader on each successful trade.
but when i sync it generates table with this SQL query

```
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "feedbacks" ("id"  S`ERIAL , "rating" "public"."enum_feedbacks_rating", "comment" VARCHAR(255), "traderId" INTEGER REFERENCES "traders" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, "feedbackClientId" INTEGER REFERENCES "traders" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, UNIQUE ("traderId", "feedbackClientId"), PRIMARY KEY ("id"));`
```

how can i remove this constraint?

```
UNIQUE ("traderId", "feedbackClientId")
```

so that i can add multiple records with same combination of traderId and feedbackClientId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution [here](https://medium.com/@arikramer24/how-to-work-around-sequelizes-unique-constraints-in-belongstomany-associations-20eb72dabeac), please post your answers if you have better solutions.